# Laravel - Order By not working with specific column name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a simple query:

```
$connectorQuery = (new Connector)->setConnection($this->customerConnection)->select([
                'connector.*']);

$total = $connectorQuery->count();
$connectors = $connectorQuery->orderBy('connector.instance', 'asc')->get()->toArray();
```

Total count works ok, in my case I have 3 records in table. If I remove the "orderBy" it returns the records.

So I tried to order by other columns and it works, so it is only an issue with "instance" column.

I found that "instance" is a reserved keyword in MySQL 8,  not sure if that is the error, so I tried using "orderByRaw" to be able to add backticks, but still nothing.

```
$connectors = $connectorQuery->orderByRaw("`connector`.`instance` ASC")->get()->toArray();
```

It is too late to change column name, any idea how to solve this issue? I am using Laravel and Mysql 8

Comment: For test purpose first column name change and try again

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Laravel will allow these but here are 3 possible options:

in SQL  you can order by the column number e.g.

```
select id, instance from t order by 2
```

Use an alias

```
select id, instance as name from t order by name
```

Define a view in the database that uses an alias on that column:

```
create view myview as
select id, instance as name from t;
```

then instead of using the table in Laravel, use that view instead.